# Cannot Schedule SAS script to run on Windows Job Scheduler

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and am trying to automate an export of a csv file.
The sas script worked as intended when I ran it within the sas console.

Followed the instructions on this document using the first method(https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2013/08/14/four-ways-to-schedule-sas-tasks), and the export works when I run it in SAS, but when I schedule the job nothing happens.

A few things to consider:

- I have to use VPN to access SAS for my organization (not sure if this effects anything)
- Not an admin on my laptop, owned by the organization

I'm looking to run on Windows task scheduler for now as it's a smaller file would be nice to have it automated on a weekly basis without having to manually do it.

Comment: Did the job produce any log output when it ran? If so please share. If you close task scheduler and open it again, can you see the job listed there? Have you tried triggering it a short time into the future so that you can confirm whether or not the trigger is working? What happens if you run the job manually without waiting for the trigger?

Comment: Can you show the contant of the bat file?

Comment: That article you linked mentions 4 different methods to schedule. Which one did you try?